# Reading PEM RSA Public Key Only using Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, public-key, pem

I am trying to use C# to read in a `.pem` file that contains only a RSA public key.  I do not have access to the private key information, nor does my application require it.  The file `myprivatekey.pem` file begins with

`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`
and ends with 
`-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`.

My current code is as follows:

```
    Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;

    using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\keys\myprivatekey.pem"))
        keyPair = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
```

However the code throws an `InvalidCastException` with the message

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.DsaPublicKeyParameters' to type
>   'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair'.

How can I use Bouncy Castle's `PemReader` to read only a public key, when no private key information is available?

Comment: A single public key is not a key pair. A key pair is a public key *and* a private key.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following code will read a public key from a given filename.  The exception handling should be changed for any production code.  This method returns an `AsymetricKeyParameter`:

```
public Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter(string pemFilename)
{
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenText(pemFilename);
    var pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(fileStream);
    var KeyParameter = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemReader.ReadObject();
    return KeyParameter;
}
```

Comment: Can this be used to read a private key as well? Then just pass in false in the cipher function such as: cipher.Init(false, privatekey). I tried this without luck.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a possible solution that reads both public and private PEM files into RSACryptoServiceProvider:

```
public class PemReaderB
{
    public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetRSAProviderFromPem(String pemstr)
    {
        CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters();
        cspParameters.KeyContainerName = "MyKeyContainer";
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);

        Func<RSACryptoServiceProvider, RsaKeyParameters, RSACryptoServiceProvider> MakePublicRCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider rcsp, RsaKeyParameters rkp) =>
        {
            RSAParameters rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(rkp);
            rcsp.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
            return rsaKey;
        };

        Func<RSACryptoServiceProvider, RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters, RSACryptoServiceProvider> MakePrivateRCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider rcsp, RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rkp) =>
        {
            RSAParameters rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(rkp);
            rcsp.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
            return rsaKey;
        };

        PemReader reader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pemstr));
        object kp = reader.ReadObject();

        // If object has Private/Public property, we have a Private PEM
        return (kp.GetType().GetProperty("Private") != null) ? MakePrivateRCSP(rsaKey, (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)(((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)kp).Private)) : MakePublicRCSP(rsaKey, (RsaKeyParameters)kp);
    }

    public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetRSAProviderFromPemFile(String pemfile)
    {
        return GetRSAProviderFromPem(File.ReadAllText(pemfile).Trim());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For Linux / .NET standard, I ended up just making a new RSACryptoServiceProvider using parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
keyPair = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
```

Use:

```
keyPair = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricKeyParameter)new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
```

Since you are only using a public key and you don't actually have a pair of keys (public & private) you can't cast it as 'AsymmetricCipherKeyPair' you should cast it as 'AsymmetricKeyParameter'.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to c0d3Junk13, I had the same issue for a PEM private key and it took me all afternoon to find the solution using the C# BouncyCastle Version 1.7 and Visual Studio 2013 Desktop Express. Don't forget to add the project reference to BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Collections;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto; 
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines; 
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;

/* 
    For an Active Directory generated pem, strip out everything in pem file before line:
    "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" and re-save.
*/
string privateKeyFileName = @"C:\CertificateTest\CS\bccrypto-net-1.7-bin\private_key3.pem";

TextReader reader = File.OpenText(privateKeyFileName);

Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters key;

using (reader = File.OpenText(privateKeyFileName))
{
    key = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
}

cipher.Init(false, key);

//Decrypting the input bytes

byte[] decipheredBytes = cipher.ProcessBlock(cipheredBytes, 0, cipheredBytes.Length);

MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decipheredBytes));
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: 
It looks like this depends on what type of key file you are using. For **ssh-keygen** keys, the private key appears to have a type of `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`, but for **openssl** keys, the private key has a type of `RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters`.

---

Bryan Jyh Herng Chong's answer no longer appears to work for me (at least with Bouncy Castle version v1.8.5). It appears `kp.GetType().GetProperty("Private")` is no longer set differently for public vs private key PEM objects. It also appears that the object returned using `PemReader.ReadObject()` is now directly a `RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters` object, so there's no longer a need to cast through a `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` object first.

I changed that line to this and it worked like a charm:

```
return (kp.GetType() == typeof(RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)) ? MakePrivateRCSP(rsaKey, (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)kp)) : MakePublicRCSP(rsaKey, (RsaKeyParameters)kp);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
Using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;


string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\key\ABCD.pem");



AsymmetricCipherKeyPair Key;

TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@path);

 PemReader pr = new PemReader(tr);
        Key = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pr.ReadObject();
        pr.Reader.Close();
        tr.Close();



         AsymmetricKeyParameter keaa = Key.Public;
```