# How to load the RSA public key from file in C#

Tags: c#, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, public-key

I need to load the following RSA public key from a file for use with the RSACryptoServiceProvider class. How can I do this?

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/syEKqEkMtQL0+d
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+izR
KbGMRtur2TYklnyVkjeeHfAggo8vWQmWesnOG55vQYHbOOFoJbk0EkwEr5R/PbKm
byXPPN8zwnS5/XXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

---

This code works with my pub key: http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/

Here is the code I am using

```
        static string RSA(string input)
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = DecodeX509PublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(GetKey()));

            return (Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input), false)));
        }

        static string GetKey()
        {
            return File.ReadAllText("master.pub").Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
            //.Replace("\n", "");
        }

        private static bool CompareBytearrays(byte[] a, byte[] b)
        {
            if (a.Length != b.Length)
                return false;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (byte c in a)
            {
                if (c != b[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public static RSACryptoServiceProvider DecodeX509PublicKey(byte[] x509key)
        {
            // encoded OID sequence for  PKCS #1 rsaEncryption szOID_RSA_RSA = "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1"
            byte[] SeqOID = { 0x30, 0x0D, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00 };
            byte[] seq = new byte[15];
            // ---------  Set up stream to read the asn.1 encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo blob  ------
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(x509key);
            BinaryReader binr = new BinaryReader(mem);    //wrap Memory Stream with BinaryReader for easy reading
            byte bt = 0;
            ushort twobytes = 0;

            try
            {

                twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                if (twobytes == 0x8130) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                    binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
                else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                    binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
                else
                    return null;

                seq = binr.ReadBytes(15);       //read the Sequence OID
                if (!CompareBytearrays(seq, SeqOID))    //make sure Sequence for OID is correct
                    return null;

                twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                if (twobytes == 0x8103) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Bit String is 03 81)
                    binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
                else if (twobytes == 0x8203)
                    binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
                else
                    return null;

                bt = binr.ReadByte();
                if (bt != 0x00)     //expect null byte next
                    return null;

                twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                if (twobytes == 0x8130) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                    binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
                else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                    binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
                else
                    return null;

                twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                byte lowbyte = 0x00;
                byte highbyte = 0x00;

                if (twobytes == 0x8102) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Integer is 02 81)
                    lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();  // read next bytes which is bytes in modulus
                else if (twobytes == 0x8202)
                {
                    highbyte = binr.ReadByte(); //advance 2 bytes
                    lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();
                }
                else
                    return null;
                byte[] modint = { lowbyte, highbyte, 0x00, 0x00 };   //reverse byte order since asn.1 key uses big endian order
                int modsize = BitConverter.ToInt32(modint, 0);

                byte firstbyte = binr.ReadByte();
                binr.BaseStream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);

                if (firstbyte == 0x00)
                {   //if first byte (highest order) of modulus is zero, don't include it
                    binr.ReadByte();    //skip this null byte
                    modsize -= 1;   //reduce modulus buffer size by 1
                }

                byte[] modulus = binr.ReadBytes(modsize);   //read the modulus bytes

                if (binr.ReadByte() != 0x02)            //expect an Integer for the exponent data
                    return null;
                int expbytes = (int)binr.ReadByte();        // should only need one byte for actual exponent data (for all useful values)
                byte[] exponent = binr.ReadBytes(expbytes);

                // ------- create RSACryptoServiceProvider instance and initialize with public key -----
                RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
                RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
                RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
                return RSA;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

            finally { binr.Close(); }

        }
```

Just call the 'RSA' method with the text you want to encrypt and you're done.

Comment: By using a `IO.StreamReader`?

Comment: possible duplication? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net

Comment: I tried converting the string into bytes using Convert.FromBase64String and then pass bytes to RSACryptoServiceProvider constructor, but it throws an exception. Same happens with X509Certificate.CreateFromFile

Comment: Perhaps you might try testing your code against a known valid public key file first, then test it against your key above.

Comment: I am now using the following code http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/ seems to work...

Answer (score 68):

You can create an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` from a PEM file using the following class (`GetRSAProviderFromPemFile` method).

**Warning:**
**Don't just copy code from StackOverflow without verification! Especially not crypto code! This code has bugs (see comments). You may want to write and run tests before using this in production (if you really have no better option).** I refuse to edit the code to fix it, as it would be just as unreliable as before without tests and an active maintainer.

**Source:**
This code seems to be taken from `opensslkey` from [this site](http://jensign.com/dotnet/opensslkey/index.html).
Copyright (c) 2000  JavaScience Consulting, Michel Gallant.
The original package was released under a BSD-like license, so it is probably OK to use it (but you may want to double-check). There is also a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/opensslkey) by the same author.

Here is the copy-pasted source code originally posted to this answer:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = PemKeyUtils.GetRSAProviderFromPemFile(  @"public_key.pem" );


public class PemKeyUtils
{
    const String pemprivheader = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const String pemprivfooter = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const String pempubheader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
    const String pempubfooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    const String pemp8header = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const String pemp8footer = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const String pemp8encheader = "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----";
    const String pemp8encfooter = "-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----";

    static bool verbose = false;

    public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetRSAProviderFromPemFile( String pemfile )
    {
        bool isPrivateKeyFile = true;
        string pemstr = File.ReadAllText( pemfile ).Trim();
        if (pemstr.StartsWith( pempubheader ) && pemstr.EndsWith( pempubfooter ))
            isPrivateKeyFile = false;

        byte[] pemkey;
        if (isPrivateKeyFile)
            pemkey = DecodeOpenSSLPrivateKey( pemstr );
        else
            pemkey = DecodeOpenSSLPublicKey( pemstr );

        if (pemkey == null)
            return null;

        if (isPrivateKeyFile)
            return DecodeRSAPrivateKey( pemkey );
        else
            return DecodeX509PublicKey( pemkey );

    }



    //--------   Get the binary RSA PUBLIC key   --------
    static byte[] DecodeOpenSSLPublicKey( String instr )
    {
        const String pempubheader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
        const String pempubfooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
        String pemstr = instr.Trim();
        byte[] binkey;
        if (!pemstr.StartsWith( pempubheader ) || !pemstr.EndsWith( pempubfooter ))
            return null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( pemstr );
        sb.Replace( pempubheader, "" );  //remove headers/footers, if present
        sb.Replace( pempubfooter, "" );

        String pubstr = sb.ToString().Trim();   //get string after removing leading/trailing whitespace

        try
        {
            binkey = Convert.FromBase64String( pubstr );
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {       //if can't b64 decode, data is not valid
            return null;
        }
        return binkey;
    }

    static RSACryptoServiceProvider DecodeX509PublicKey(byte[] x509Key)
    {
        // encoded OID sequence for  PKCS #1 rsaEncryption szOID_RSA_RSA = "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1"
        byte[] seqOid = { 0x30, 0x0D, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00 };
        // ---------  Set up stream to read the asn.1 encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo blob  ------
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(x509Key))
        {
            using (var binr = new BinaryReader(mem))    //wrap Memory Stream with BinaryReader for easy reading
            {
                try
                {
                    var twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                    switch (twobytes)
                    {
                        case 0x8130:
                            binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
                            break;
                        case 0x8230:
                            binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
                            break;
                        default:
                            return null;
                    }

                    var seq = binr.ReadBytes(15);
                    if (!CompareBytearrays(seq, seqOid))  //make sure Sequence for OID is correct
                        return null;

                    twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                    if (twobytes == 0x8103) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Bit String is 03 81)
                        binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
                    else if (twobytes == 0x8203)
                        binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
                    else
                        return null;

                    var bt = binr.ReadByte();
                    if (bt != 0x00)     //expect null byte next
                        return null;

                    twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                    if (twobytes == 0x8130) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                        binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
                    else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                        binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
                    else
                        return null;

                    twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
                    byte lowbyte = 0x00;
                    byte highbyte = 0x00;

                    if (twobytes == 0x8102) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Integer is 02 81)
                        lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();  // read next bytes which is bytes in modulus
                    else if (twobytes == 0x8202)
                    {
                        highbyte = binr.ReadByte(); //advance 2 bytes
                        lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();
                    }
                    else
                        return null;
                    byte[] modint = { lowbyte, highbyte, 0x00, 0x00 };   //reverse byte order since asn.1 key uses big endian order
                    int modsize = BitConverter.ToInt32(modint, 0);

                    byte firstbyte = binr.ReadByte();
                    binr.BaseStream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);

                    if (firstbyte == 0x00)
                    {   //if first byte (highest order) of modulus is zero, don't include it
                        binr.ReadByte();    //skip this null byte
                        modsize -= 1;   //reduce modulus buffer size by 1
                    }

                    byte[] modulus = binr.ReadBytes(modsize); //read the modulus bytes

                    if (binr.ReadByte() != 0x02)            //expect an Integer for the exponent data
                        return null;
                    int expbytes = binr.ReadByte();        // should only need one byte for actual exponent data (for all useful values)
                    byte[] exponent = binr.ReadBytes(expbytes);

                    // We don't really need to print anything but if we insist to...
                    //showBytes("\nExponent", exponent);
                    //showBytes("\nModulus", modulus);

                    // ------- create RSACryptoServiceProvider instance and initialize with public key -----
                    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                    RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = new RSAParameters
                    {
                        Modulus = modulus,
                        Exponent = exponent
                    };
                    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);
                    return rsa;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //------- Parses binary ans.1 RSA private key; returns RSACryptoServiceProvider  ---
    static RSACryptoServiceProvider DecodeRSAPrivateKey( byte[] privkey )
    {
        byte[] MODULUS, E, D, P, Q, DP, DQ, IQ;

        // ---------  Set up stream to decode the asn.1 encoded RSA private key  ------
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream( privkey );
        BinaryReader binr = new BinaryReader( mem );    //wrap Memory Stream with BinaryReader for easy reading
        byte bt = 0;
        ushort twobytes = 0;
        int elems = 0;
        try
        {
            twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
            if (twobytes == 0x8130) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                binr.ReadByte();    //advance 1 byte
            else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                binr.ReadInt16();   //advance 2 bytes
            else
                return null;

            twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
            if (twobytes != 0x0102) //version number
                return null;
            bt = binr.ReadByte();
            if (bt != 0x00)
                return null;


            //------  all private key components are Integer sequences ----
            elems = GetIntegerSize( binr );
            MODULUS = binr.ReadBytes( elems );

            elems = GetIntegerSize( binr );
            E = binr.ReadBytes( elems );

            elems = GetIntegerSize( binr );
            D = binr.ReadBytes( elems );

            elems = GetIntegerSize( binr );
            P = binr.ReadBytes( elems );

            elems = GetIntegerSize( binr );
            Q = binr.ReadBytes( elems );

            elems = GetIntegerSize( binr );
            DP = binr.ReadBytes( elems );

            elems = GetIntegerSize( binr );
            DQ = binr.ReadBytes( elems );

            elems = GetIntegerSize( binr );
            IQ = binr.ReadBytes( elems );

            Console.WriteLine( "showing components .." );
            if (verbose)
            {
                showBytes( "\nModulus", MODULUS );
                showBytes( "\nExponent", E );
                showBytes( "\nD", D );
                showBytes( "\nP", P );
                showBytes( "\nQ", Q );
                showBytes( "\nDP", DP );
                showBytes( "\nDQ", DQ );
                showBytes( "\nIQ", IQ );
            }

            // ------- create RSACryptoServiceProvider instance and initialize with public key -----
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            RSAParameters RSAparams = new RSAParameters();
            RSAparams.Modulus = MODULUS;
            RSAparams.Exponent = E;
            RSAparams.D = D;
            RSAparams.P = P;
            RSAparams.Q = Q;
            RSAparams.DP = DP;
            RSAparams.DQ = DQ;
            RSAparams.InverseQ = IQ;
            RSA.ImportParameters( RSAparams );
            return RSA;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally { binr.Close(); }
    }

    private static int GetIntegerSize( BinaryReader binr )
    {
        byte bt = 0;
        byte lowbyte = 0x00;
        byte highbyte = 0x00;
        int count = 0;
        bt = binr.ReadByte();
        if (bt != 0x02)     //expect integer
            return 0;
        bt = binr.ReadByte();

        if (bt == 0x81)
            count = binr.ReadByte();    // data size in next byte
        else
            if (bt == 0x82)
            {
                highbyte = binr.ReadByte(); // data size in next 2 bytes
                lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();
                byte[] modint = { lowbyte, highbyte, 0x00, 0x00 };
                count = BitConverter.ToInt32( modint, 0 );
            }
            else
            {
                count = bt;     // we already have the data size
            }



        while (binr.ReadByte() == 0x00)
        {   //remove high order zeros in data
            count -= 1;
        }
        binr.BaseStream.Seek( -1, SeekOrigin.Current );     //last ReadByte wasn't a removed zero, so back up a byte
        return count;
    }

    //-----  Get the binary RSA PRIVATE key, decrypting if necessary ----
    static byte[] DecodeOpenSSLPrivateKey( String instr )
    {
        const String pemprivheader = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
        const String pemprivfooter = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
        String pemstr = instr.Trim();
        byte[] binkey;
        if (!pemstr.StartsWith( pemprivheader ) || !pemstr.EndsWith( pemprivfooter ))
            return null;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( pemstr );
        sb.Replace( pemprivheader, "" );  //remove headers/footers, if present
        sb.Replace( pemprivfooter, "" );

        String pvkstr = sb.ToString().Trim();   //get string after removing leading/trailing whitespace

        try
        {        // if there are no PEM encryption info lines, this is an UNencrypted PEM private key
            binkey = Convert.FromBase64String( pvkstr );
            return binkey;
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {       //if can't b64 decode, it must be an encrypted private key
            //Console.WriteLine("Not an unencrypted OpenSSL PEM private key");  
        }

        StringReader str = new StringReader( pvkstr );

        //-------- read PEM encryption info. lines and extract salt -----
        if (!str.ReadLine().StartsWith( "Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED" ))
            return null;
        String saltline = str.ReadLine();
        if (!saltline.StartsWith( "DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC," ))
            return null;
        String saltstr = saltline.Substring( saltline.IndexOf( "," ) + 1 ).Trim();
        byte[] salt = new byte[saltstr.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length; i++)
            salt[i] = Convert.ToByte( saltstr.Substring( i * 2, 2 ), 16 );
        if (!(str.ReadLine() == ""))
            return null;

        //------ remaining b64 data is encrypted RSA key ----
        String encryptedstr = str.ReadToEnd();

        try
        {   //should have b64 encrypted RSA key now
            binkey = Convert.FromBase64String( encryptedstr );
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {  // bad b64 data.
            return null;
        }

        //------ Get the 3DES 24 byte key using PDK used by OpenSSL ----

        SecureString despswd = GetSecPswd( "Enter password to derive 3DES key==>" );
        //Console.Write("\nEnter password to derive 3DES key: ");
        //String pswd = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] deskey = GetOpenSSL3deskey( salt, despswd, 1, 2 );    // count=1 (for OpenSSL implementation); 2 iterations to get at least 24 bytes
        if (deskey == null)
            return null;
        //showBytes("3DES key", deskey) ;

        //------ Decrypt the encrypted 3des-encrypted RSA private key ------
        byte[] rsakey = DecryptKey( binkey, deskey, salt ); //OpenSSL uses salt value in PEM header also as 3DES IV
        if (rsakey != null)
            return rsakey;  //we have a decrypted RSA private key
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Failed to decrypt RSA private key; probably wrong password." );
            return null;
        }
    }


    // ----- Decrypt the 3DES encrypted RSA private key ----------

    static byte[] DecryptKey( byte[] cipherData, byte[] desKey, byte[] IV )
    {
        MemoryStream memst = new MemoryStream();
        TripleDES alg = TripleDES.Create();
        alg.Key = desKey;
        alg.IV = IV;
        try
        {
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream( memst, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write );
            cs.Write( cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length );
            cs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( exc.Message );
            return null;
        }
        byte[] decryptedData = memst.ToArray();
        return decryptedData;
    }

    //-----   OpenSSL PBKD uses only one hash cycle (count); miter is number of iterations required to build sufficient bytes ---
    static byte[] GetOpenSSL3deskey( byte[] salt, SecureString secpswd, int count, int miter )
    {
        IntPtr unmanagedPswd = IntPtr.Zero;
        int HASHLENGTH = 16;    //MD5 bytes
        byte[] keymaterial = new byte[HASHLENGTH * miter];     //to store contatenated Mi hashed results


        byte[] psbytes = new byte[secpswd.Length];
        unmanagedPswd = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocAnsi( secpswd );
        Marshal.Copy( unmanagedPswd, psbytes, 0, psbytes.Length );
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocAnsi( unmanagedPswd );

        //UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        //byte[] psbytes = utf8.GetBytes(pswd);

        // --- contatenate salt and pswd bytes into fixed data array ---
        byte[] data00 = new byte[psbytes.Length + salt.Length];
        Array.Copy( psbytes, data00, psbytes.Length );      //copy the pswd bytes
        Array.Copy( salt, 0, data00, psbytes.Length, salt.Length ); //concatenate the salt bytes

        // ---- do multi-hashing and contatenate results  D1, D2 ...  into keymaterial bytes ----
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] result = null;
        byte[] hashtarget = new byte[HASHLENGTH + data00.Length];   //fixed length initial hashtarget

        for (int j = 0; j < miter; j++)
        {
            // ----  Now hash consecutively for count times ------
            if (j == 0)
                result = data00;    //initialize 
            else
            {
                Array.Copy( result, hashtarget, result.Length );
                Array.Copy( data00, 0, hashtarget, result.Length, data00.Length );
                result = hashtarget;
                //Console.WriteLine("Updated new initial hash target:") ;
                //showBytes(result) ;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                result = md5.ComputeHash( result );
            Array.Copy( result, 0, keymaterial, j * HASHLENGTH, result.Length );  //contatenate to keymaterial
        }
        //showBytes("Final key material", keymaterial);
        byte[] deskey = new byte[24];
        Array.Copy( keymaterial, deskey, deskey.Length );

        Array.Clear( psbytes, 0, psbytes.Length );
        Array.Clear( data00, 0, data00.Length );
        Array.Clear( result, 0, result.Length );
        Array.Clear( hashtarget, 0, hashtarget.Length );
        Array.Clear( keymaterial, 0, keymaterial.Length );

        return deskey;
    }

    static SecureString GetSecPswd( String prompt )
    {
        SecureString password = new SecureString();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write( prompt );
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;

        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey( true );
            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine();
                return password;
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                // remove the last asterisk from the screen...
                if (password.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition( Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop );
                    Console.Write( " " );
                    Console.SetCursorPosition( Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop );
                    password.RemoveAt( password.Length - 1 );
                }
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine();
                return password;
            }
            else if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit( cki.KeyChar ) || Char.IsSymbol( cki.KeyChar ))
            {
                if (password.Length < 20)
                {
                    password.AppendChar( cki.KeyChar );
                    Console.Write( "*" );
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Beep();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Beep();
            }
        }
    }

    static bool CompareBytearrays( byte[] a, byte[] b )
    {
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return false;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (byte c in a)
        {
            if (c != b[i])
                return false;
            i++;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void showBytes( String info, byte[] data )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0}  [{1} bytes]", info, data.Length );
        for (int i = 1; i <= data.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write( "{0:X2}  ", data[i - 1] );
            if (i % 16 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine( "\n\n" );
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for you that the OP didn't mark your answer as Accepted. It's a really good one.

Comment: Well... It doesn't work this openssl keys for example, neither from some libs, you can take a look at: https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt/issues/93#issuecomment-388213496 ^^'

Comment: This code (particularly the skipping of leading zeroes in `GetIntegerSize`) can cause a `CryptographicException` in `ImportParameters` due to values being too short. It only happens sporadically. Not skipping leading zeroes can cause the same exception due to values being too long. It is unclear if values can end up too short without skipping leading zeroes in `GetIntegerSize`, as this depends on the input. See stackoverflow.com/a/39135984/2279059 for details.

Comment: string private_key = File.ReadAllText(private_key_file).Trim();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"-----(BEGIN|END) (RSA|OPENSSH|ENCRYPTED) PRIVATE KEY-----[\W]*");
string private_key_base64 = regex.Replace(private_key, "");
byte[] bytes_privake_key = Convert.FromBase64String(private_key_base64);
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(bytes_privake_key), out bytesRead);

Comment: As of 2022 this is not a good solution, as OP mentioned, it's unsafe, unmaintained, untested and therefore shouldn't be used. See @Kevin solution using `RSA.Create()` for a modern, safe and simple solution.

Answer (score 9):

As of .Net 5.0 you can import an RSA public key from a string like so:

```
var rsaPublicKey = RSA.Create();
rsaPublicKey.ImportFromPem(publicKeyString);
```

If you don't know how to read a file to a string see

[How to read an entire file to a string using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7387085/5517088)

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about an X509 certificate:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("your_cert_file.crt", FileMode.Open);
byte[] certBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(certBytes, 0, (Int32)fs.Length);
fs.Close();
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate x509cert = 
    new X509Certificate(certBytes);
Console.WriteLine(x509cert.GetPublicKey());
Console.WriteLine(x509cert.GetPublicKeyString());
```

**EDITED after the comment of @hkproj done in "7/16/2012 15:04:58 Z":**

Looking around here I found "[Reading PEM RSA Public Key Only using Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367152/1350308)".
I guess what you want is this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"c:\RSA.txt"))
{
    Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader pr = 
        new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(reader);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemObject po = pr.ReadPemObject();

    Console.WriteLine("PemObject, Type: " + po.Type);
    Console.WriteLine("PemObject, Length: " + po.Content.Length);
}
```

However, with your file I get an error: `System.IO.IOException : base64 data appears to be truncated`.

So changing your file to something like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/syEKqEkMtQL0+d
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX+izR
KbGMRtur2TYklnyVkjeeHfAggo8vWQmWesnOG55vQYHbOOFoJbk0EkwEr5R/PbKm
byXPPN8zwnS5/XXXXXXXXXXXXZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The result is:

```
PemObject, Type: PUBLIC KEY
PemObject, Length: 192
```

Comment: already tried. Didn't work. Throws 'CryptographicException' with this message: Cannot find the requested object.

Answer (score 3):

Are you speaking about certificates stored in file?

If you have an object like:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate;
```

you can use following code:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaprovider =
                    (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key;
```

and then use the class RSACryptoServiceProvider (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

To load an X509Certificate2 use its constructor (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx).

This program works fine for me:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try 
        {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = 
                new X509Certificate2("<PFX Certificate Path", "<Certificate-Password>");
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaprovider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Throws 'CryptographicException' with this message: Cannot find the requested object

Comment: I know that constructor waits binary certificate (DER formar), not base64 one ... reading your solution I notice this "FromBase64String" so you are using a Base64 binary format?

Comment: The certificate is saved into base64 format. So I am using FromBase64String to convert it into a byte array, so that I can pass it to the constructor. Btw, I solved. If you look at my solution, I am using a method I "stole" from the "opensslkey" tool (which, is open source). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
string private_key = File.ReadAllText(private_key_file).Trim();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"-----(BEGIN|END) (RSA|OPENSSH|ENCRYPTED) PRIVATE KEY-----[\W]*");
string private_key_base64 = regex.Replace(private_key, "");
byte[] bytes_privake_key = Convert.FromBase64String(private_key_base64);
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(bytes_privake_key), out bytesRead);
```

Comment: Can you add rsa instance also.

Comment: @Andy Tao what is rsa here?