# C# (.NET) RSACryptoServiceProvider import/export x509 public key blob and PKCS8 private key blob

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

first of all let me state that I'm not a crypto expert but i know the basics.

I want to be able to:

1. Get a RSACryptoServiceProvider instance from a X509 Public Key blob
2. Get a RSACryptoServiceProvider instance from a PKCS8 Private Key blob
3. Export the public key from a RSACryptoServiceProvider instance as a x509 Public Key blob
4. Export the private key from a RSACryptoServiceProvider instance as a PKCS8 blob

Comment: You are encrypting with private key and decrypting with the public one. This is called digital-signature and has specific methods in Java and C#. Really is what you want to do? Usually encryption is performed with public key and decryption with private.

Comment: Note also that importing a RSA public key is not trivial.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091460/rsa-read-publickey

Comment: @pedrofb i was already onto it. 
I've got to parse the binary asn.1 X509PKInfo into a RSAParameters object. I'll provide a code solution when once i finish it.

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right track @pedrofb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around all day, i've found this [repository (thanks a lot jrnker)](https://github.com/jrnker/CSharp-easy-RSA-PEM) and i selected the code i needed to able to met the goals 1, 2 and 3.

Since Jrnker's only provides methods to get a RSACryptoServiceProvider from a PKCS1 blob (and what i needed was a RSACryptoServiceProvider from a PKCS8 blob) i kept looking to met goal number 4. Then i've found [Michel Gallant's "opensslkey.cs"](http://www.jensign.com/opensslkey/opensslkey.cs) and i selected the needed code to met goal number 4.

Then i've proceeded to compile a class with needed methods and classes.

Here's my demo class:

```
using System;

namespace RSAKeyTests
{
    class Demo
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //EXPORTED KEYS
            string importedPublicKeyBase64 = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhbVC4aUR+XRCepBcPlod69wruXqwW9yL/YJYvuaQ33QxUoAehQ0z4SuphHwEPxQp/qLqucmE6XKlEeTksFAmaGM88uuGessqMZmdu9WFhc07MWLTCifR43IRtGEeWeFSWjUI6mNRrShP3QQ3+Z6e7w+HRA2RpmgNgEhJRvECHAKpcpHvP9o5Sq6q/dIAyR6NEjRFhfud27rFtnWrLj+ZmIsScemvks4vh8V3n8EzxxRE8nzVuZYr4v4NNH+q95XgIadHZ1Y6ICXJgX2NfacNRQl9+SEv0Wo8lbmFSIO3jHqyiWuSugv7R3/rQPRXHT6HJAtw0tBiPOBitMkTzqOvIwIDAQAB";
            string importedPrivateKeyBase64 = "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";
            byte[] importedPublicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(importedPublicKeyBase64);
            byte[] importedPrivateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(importedPrivateKeyBase64);

            //PRINT INFO
            Console.WriteLine("------   IMPORTED KEY PAIR:   ------\n");
            Console.WriteLine("PUBLIC KEY:\n"+importedPublicKeyBase64+"\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("PRIVATE KEY:\n" + importedPrivateKeyBase64 + "\n\n");

            //GENERATING RSACRYPTOSERVICEPROVIDER FROM X509 PUBLIC KEY BLOB
            using (var providerFromX509pubKey = RSAKeyUtils.DecodePublicKey(importedPublicKeyBytes))
            {
                providerFromX509pubKey.PersistKeyInCsp = false; //DO NOT STORE IN KEYSTORE

                //EXPORT TO X509 PUBLIC KEY BLOB
                byte[] x509pubKeyBytes = RSAKeyUtils.PublicKeyToX509(providerFromX509pubKey.ExportParameters(false));

                //CONVERT TO BASE64
                string x509pubKeyBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(x509pubKeyBytes);

                //PRINT INFO
                Console.WriteLine("------   PUBLIC KEY TO EXPORT   ------");
                Console.WriteLine("Public key to export matches imported? "+importedPublicKeyBase64.Equals(x509pubKeyBase64));
                Console.WriteLine(x509pubKeyBase64+"\n\n");
            }

            //GENERATING RSACRYPTOSERVICEPROVIDER FROM PKCS8 PRIVATE KEY BLOB
            using (var providerFromPKCS8privKey = RSAKeyUtils.DecodePrivateKeyInfo(importedPrivateKeyBytes))
            {
                providerFromPKCS8privKey.PersistKeyInCsp = false; //DO NOT STORE IN KEYSTORE

                //EXPORT TO PKCS8 PRIVATE KEY BLOB
                byte[] pkcs8privKeyBytes = RSAKeyUtils.PrivateKeyToPKCS8(providerFromPKCS1privKey.ExportParameters(true));

                //CONVERT TO BASE64
                string pkcs8privKeyBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pkcs8privKeyBytes);

                //PRINT INFO
                Console.WriteLine("------   PRIVATE KEY TO EXPORT   ------");
                Console.WriteLine("Private key to export matches imported? " + importedPrivateKeyBase64.Equals(pkcs8privKeyBase64));
                Console.WriteLine(pkcs8privKeyBase64);
            }

                //PREVENTS THE PROGRAM FROM EXITING
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's the **"RSAKeyUtils"** class i've compiled.](http://pastebin.com/jxAm7fsb)

I hope this can be useful to someone else.

Comment: It was very helpful your RSAKeyUtils, thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

First, `byte` in Java isn't the same as `byte` in .Net. Java only has signed integers, so a Java `byte` ranges from -128 to 127, while a .Net `byte` ranges from 0 to 255. But I'm not sure, if this is the problem, as a Base64 string relies on the bit pattern. Try to use a larger type in its positive range and use the lower 8 bits only.

Second, the message about the bad provider version might indicate either the above cause or might just be a misleading text, that won't really help. I remember I once encountered the same error message and had a hard time to find the actual cause. A quick search some minutes ago hasn't been successful either. In my case I had a completely other situation, so I won't be able to point my finger on your problem directly. Instead I would recommend to check padding, encrypt mode, base64 translation and related stuff around the RSA algorithm and try to find an alternative way to achieve the same as you wanted before. On the way to there you might stumble across the actual problem.

Comment: The padding, the encrypt mode and the base64 translation are fine since i've been relying on them a long time ago and never had issues with them. The problem is in the key representation for sure...