# RSA encrypt a string from PEM public key in dotnet core

Tags: encryption, .net-core, rsa, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm trying to encrypt a string using a PEM public key file in dotnet core (1.1) and my question is:  How do I do this?

I thought this would simply be a case of:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2("path_to_public_key.pem");
using (var rsa = cert.GetRSAPublicKey())
{
    // encrypt here
}
```

However, when I try to new up the certificate I get the following error:

> error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error

The PEM file looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
... ANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFA ...
(loads more text)
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I've checked the pem file and there are no extraneous ^M characters anywhere (as from a suggest cause of the error [here](https://serverfault.com/a/317038)).

(I'm on macOS Sierra if that makes any difference)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have a public key and not a certificate. I guess you shouldn't use `X509Certificate2`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you!  You sent me down the right path.  (It's so obvious when someone points it out!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artjom B's comment sent me down the right path.  A public key is indeed not a certificate.

Solution came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32243171/2022190) excellent post.

For dotnet core (which doesn't have a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class) I made a couple of minor modifications.  You can return an `RSAParameters` object from `GetRSAProviderFromPemFile`, you can then use that like:

```
using (var rsa = RSA.Create()
{
   rsa.ImportParameters(GetRSAProviderFromPemFile("path_to_pem.pem"));
   var encrypted = rsa.Encrypt( ... );
}
```

Comment: How did you initialize RSAParameters with given example of `GetRSAProviderFromPemFile`?

Comment: But `RSACryptoServiceProvider` is available in .NET Core since v1.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netcore-3.1#moniker-applies-to