# how do I create a pfx compatible with X509Certificate2 with openssl

Tags: c#, .net, openssl

I'm trying to create an RSA keypair that I can use with `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` using OpenSSL.

The PFX I've managed to generate gives me this stack trace

create a private key, unencrypted (I realize this is not best practice)

`openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048`

create a public key from the private key

`openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem`

create a certificate file from the private key

`openssl req -x509 -key private.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -subj "/C=US/ST=Colorado/L=Colorado Springs/O=Contoso/OU=Security/CN=mypurpose.contoso.org"`

create a pfx file using the self-signed certificate

`openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pem -inkey private.pem -export -out combined.pfx`

> prompts for a password to secure the pkcs

Trying to instantiate the instance of `X509Certificate2` with

`new X509Certificate2(@"C:\path\to\combined.pfx", "password",  X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);`

```
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at Program.Main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace is telling me everything.

```
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
```

This means that there's no CERTIFICATE in my PFX file, because I used `-nocerts` in the `openssl pkcs12` command.

> In cryptography, PKCS #12 defines an archive file format for storing
>   many cryptography objects as a single file. It is commonly used to
>   bundle a private key with its X.509 certificate or to bundle all the
>   members of a chain of trust. [PKCS 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12)

A pkcs12 file really wants to contain something besides just a Private/Public Key, It wants an X.509 certificate; which is:

- Certificate Version
- Serial Number
- Signature Algorithm
- Issuer
- Validity Not Before
- Validity Not After.

This is the final command that worked the way I wanted to:

`openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pem -inkey private.pem -export -clcerts -out combined.pfx -passout pass:`

This allows me to instantiate using this code:

`new X509Certificate2(@"C:\path\to\combined.pfx", (string)null,  X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);`

There's some additional code I'm using to load the private.pem and public.pem generated by `openssl genrsa` and `openssl rsa` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32243171/26877.
This code is loading the raw PEM data (just the private/public keys) into `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instance, which can be used to encrypt & decrypt.