# Encode on .Net Core do decode on Java

Tags: java, .net-core, rsa

I have to encode a string on my .Net Core 2.2 lib using the following certificate provided:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>   MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCVMkaF50qEKdSFIiY+nzj4Nh6c
>   aQDrrFVxDLNoMdM1O2BfxvqfJNE+4FNHYUKShQgKVrpx6BO1dPEgDrFK3NQPLOC+
>   Im/gA2skUMIDZtQt8kX5YXGRT5JkV3hM2lJQFiagf/06oqcI8WyGnHUQwfJueg7t
>   ItUZAx3sQTJfuvlocQIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Regular X509Certificate2 can't load/use it but I was able to do it using [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506891/how-to-load-the-rsa-public-key-from-file-in-c-sharp/32243171#32243171)

The problem is that the other end, Java (no further info at the time), can't seem to decrypt it!

Looking around the web i noticed that its common for java to use PKCS #8, while .net uses PKCS #1.

The error im getting back from the server is: "Illegal Base64 Caracter 7d"...

I tried to base64 encode my payload before encryption but that didn't work also.

Can anyone tell me:

1. Will a PCKS8 be able to decrypt a string encrypted by PKCS1?
2. Is there a PKCS8 implementation for .Net Core 2.x?

EDIT 1:
I went to this [site here](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption), encrypted the message using the certificate i provided above and submitted the result to my endpoint and it work...

Comment: *"I tried to base64 encode my payload before encryption"* Base-64 is applied to the encrypted binary data to get text data, since some data exchange and/or transmission protocols don't like binary data.

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize it but you've posted absolutely no code at all. How can we debug phantom code?